# Qt: Changing mouse cursor while dragging

Tags: c++, qt

How can I change the mouse cursor while dragging? I don't want the Blocking cursor or the Arrow with the Plus sign to be displayed, just the arrow cursor.

I'm using Qt 4.6.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [setDragCursor](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdrag.html#setDragCursor). Note this takes a QPixmap, so you can't just pick the arrow cursor - you need to give it an image. It doesn't look like you can use an alternative native cursor.

There has been [some](http://labs.trolltech.com/forums/topic/370) [discussion](http://old.nabble.com/How-to-change-the-Drag---Drop-cursor-during-a-drag-operation--td20549774.html) on this.

Comment: I tried that, but no luck at all. Maybe it's an X thing. I think a read something about this not working on some X desktops. I'm on Fedora 10, using KDE.